# Same color text in nano editor when logged in to the server with cmder / conemu

Tags: colors, conemu, cmder, nano

I saw some people have a friendly color scheme in Nano editor, e.g. words inside brackets highlighted, comments highlights etc.

Looks like I fail to get my Nano editor become more user friendly in terms of colors, despite my different color schemes I choose in cmder.

All the text in Nano is of the same color.

What am I missing?

Comment: Ask the people who have "friendly color scheme"

Comment: @Toto, I would if I could, but those were screencasts.

Comment: Did you try this ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/90013/how-do-i-enable-syntax-highlighting-in-nano